# Setting up Git repository using AWS Code Deploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

I have setup AWS Code Deploy with my github project. Deployment works without fail. When I login to EC2 instance, I see my project folder and all the files, but don't see the project as a git repository.
I can run `git init` and it will be git repo, but when I push the latest commit for the second time using code deploy, I will not have the recent git commit history.
Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

CodeDeploy will only deploy the files, not the entire GIT repository itself.

This is intentional. You would not normally want the repository itself on a server, you would only want the files.

Code development, commits, etc are done on a different server, not on the server you deploy to.

Comment: The reason I wanted it to be a git repository on server is because we use git submodules quite a bit. So after the files are copied over from github, I need to run `git submodule update` which will update submodules defined in `.gitmodules` file

Comment: Yes I understand.  CodeDeploy will not do this. An option would be to build the project via Jenkins, and then upload that to S3 and do and S3 based CodeDeploy.